# Password protecting Rails site running on Nginx and Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, nginx, passenger, password-protection

I want to protect my newly deployed Rails 3 app with the basic http authentication. It's running on the latest Nginx/Passenger and I'm using the following Nginx directive to protect the web root directory:

```
location = / {
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
}
```

htpasswd file was generated using Apache htpasswd utililty. However, after entering correct username and password I'm getting transferred to the 403 Forbidden error page. Analyzing Nginx error log revealed this:

```
directory index of "/var/www/mysite/public/" is forbidden, client: 108.14.212.10, server: mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "mysite.com"
```

Obviously, I don't want to list the contents of the mysite/public directory. How can I configure this properly so the Rails app starts after I enter my login info?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to re-specify passenger_enabled in the location block.

Comment: Add "passenger_enabled on;" inside the location block.

Comment: Make sure you restart NginX instead of reloading it: `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`

Answer (score 6):

You can [let Rails handle the authentication](http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication)

```
# application_controller.rb
before_filter :authenticate

protected

def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
    username == "foo" && password == "bar"
  end
end
```

also you should set `config.serve_static_assets = true` in your `environment.rb` (or `applicaion.rb` in Rails 3) so that the static assets in `public` go through the same filter.

Answer (score 2):

Check your Nginx error log. `403` means that you got the path to your password file wrong.

Comment: I checked, when the path was wrong I had  [error] 19756#0: *1 open() "/opt/nginx/conf/htpasswd" failed (2: No such file or directory)... So I'm pretty sure that now my path is correct.

Comment: Are there any other errors in your log? Did you create your passwords in crypt() format (and not MD5, as Nginx doesn't support them)?