# Nginx + fastcgi: how to send basic auth

Tags: http, nginx, cgi, fastcgi

I am using Nginx and FastCGI to accept POSTs to a C based CGI program as an API. It works fine, so now I want to have the client use a key to identify itself, like key:pass@api.sample.com.

When I turn on auth_basic in the nginx config file, and specify an auth_basic_user_file, it requires the user to be in the file.  This doesn't work for me - I don't want to maintain an htpasswd file for every key I create.  I really want to just pass the key:pass to my cgi program to handle it.  Rails (passenger) does this somehow, so I know it is possible.

Is there some kind of rewrite, or something I can do to pass at least the key (username, or $remote_user) portion to my cgi program?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Basic auth can't be customised this way, so you need to use something external. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171454/password-protecting-rails-site-running-on-nginx-and-phusion-passenger) you can find something useful.

Comment: Of course it can be done. You just need to pass the Authorization header to your CGI program with `fastcgi_pass_header Authorization` and then handle it there. Look for any old example on how to handle Basic authentication in C, Perl, or Bash CGI scripts.