# What simple password protection options do I have?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a single user CMS application and I want to keep authentication lightweight so I don't need a full blown authentication system.

My admin section will have custom admin pages that I will create to update the db, write content, and I will also maybe even use the admin gem for some things.

I just want to lock down these protected pages.

Any simple yet secure options out there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171454/password-protecting-rails-site-running-on-nginx-and-phusion-passenger

Comment: does bycrypt fit your purpose ? https://gist.github.com/thebucknerlife/10090014

Answer (score 1):

You might like this [clearance](https://everydayrails.com/2016/01/23/clearance-rails-authentication.html). It is a full-power authentication, yet still very lightweight.